# What is a good web application SQL Server data mart implementation in ElasticSearch?

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, kibana-4, star-schema, datamart

Coming from a RDBMS background and trying to wrap my head around ElasticSearch data storage patterns...

Currently in SQL Server, we have a star schema data mart, `RecordData`.  Rows are organized by user ID, geographic location that pertains to the rest of the searchable record, title and description (which are free text search fields).

I would like to move this over to ElasticSearch, and have read about creating a separate index per user.  If I understand this correctly, with this suggestion, I would be creating a `RecordData` type in each user index, correct?  What is a recommended naming convention for user indices that will be simple for [Kibana](https://www.elastic.co/products/kibana) analysis?

One issue I have with this recommendation is, how would you organize multiple web applications on the ES server?  You wouldn't want to have all those user indices all over the place?

Is it so bad to have one index per application, and type per SQL Server table?

Since in SQL Server, we have other tables for user configuration, based on user ID's, I take it that I could then create new ES types in user indices for configuration.  Is this a recommended pattern?  I would rather not have two data base systems for this web application.

Suggestions welcome, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went through the same thing, and there are a few things to take into account.

**Data Modeling**

You say you use a star schema today. Elasticsearch is typically appropriate for denormalized data where the totality of the information resides in each document unlike with a star schema. If you can live with denormalized, that is fine but I assume that since you already have star schema, denormalized data is not an option because you don't want to go and update millions of documents each time the location name change for example(if i understand the use case). At least in my use case that wasn't an option.

**What are Elasticsearch options for normalized data?**

This leads us to think of how to put star schema like data in a system like Elasticsearch. There are a few options in the documentation, the main ones i focused were

- Nested Objects - more details at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html . In nested objects the entire information is kept in a single document, meaning one location and its related users would be in a single document. That may make it not optimal becasue the document will be huge and again, a change in the location name will require to update the entire document. So this is better but still not optimal.
- Parent - Child Relationship - more details at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/parent-child.html . In this case the location and the User records would be kepts in separate indices similarly to a relational database. This seems to be the right modeling for what we need. The only major issue with this option is the fact that Kibana 4 does not provide ways to manipulate/aggregate documents based on parent/child relationship as of this writing. So if you main driver for using Elasticsearch is Kibana(this was mine), that kind of eliminates the option. If you want to benefit from the elasticsearch speed as an engine this seems to be the desired option for your use case.

In my opinion once you got right the data modeling all of your questions will be easier to answer.

Regarding the organization of the servers themselves, the way we organize that is by having a separate cluster of 3 elasticsearch nodes behind a Load Balancer(all of that is hosted on a cloud) and then have all your Web Applications connect to that cluster using the Elasticsearch API.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for the info. Re: Parent/child: user records kept in separate indices... Do you mean types (tables)?  How would you organize multiple applications using an ES server - one index per app?

Comment: Separate types. One index per app is fine, the question is again how data is modeled and if you envision having queries on 2 indexes.